# Send Email with attachment to a specific recipiant , using share Content WinRT

Tags: email, windows-runtime, share, attachment, mailto

I'm using WinRT and I want to send an email with attachment to a specific recipient programatically, that means the user of the app will not write the recipient address.
I found to solutions that dont correspond to my needs.

the first one is to use mailto protocol like this :

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=ratatata@gmail.com&subject=our first subject &body=as you know this is our first mail baby ");
```

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);

this solution allow me to specify the recipient but the mailto protocol dont support attachement.

the second one is by using Share Content , like this microsoft sample ,
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84

this solution allow me to attach any type of files , but the user of the app should write the email address of the recipient.

NB: any other methods using MessageEmail , and system.net.mail dont work !

Any help please !!